# Redirect client cloud traffic

Tags: firewall, proxy, cloud, microsoft-office-365

We recently moved our email to Office365 which has as expected put additional strain on our Internet connection. However, we are moving some services to the cloud which will stretch our Internet connection thin.

Our concept solution is to acquire another high speed Internet connection and route all cloud traffic through that connection and general browsing through a cheaper asynchronous Internet connection.

However, we can't seem to identify any enterprise grade software that will be a proxy and firewall and reroute traffic as required.

Is anyone familiar with software than can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll do much better to simply use a network device that can do outbound load balancing, based on sessions, percentage of bandwidth used, etc. I'm answering your question as if it was a request for info about a technology, rather than an explicit product request.